# using flask virtualenv on remote host (not locally)

Tags: apache, debugging, flask, virtualenv, wsgi

I have a CentOS 7 WSGI enables Apache Httpd server (on a VirtualBox machine) and it serves my developing Flask site at http://www.myflask.com on port 80.

Since I can't debug there (even if I tried everything I could), like I can on a local version set in a virutalenv at http://127.0.0.1:5000, I was trying to do this:

- setting up a virtualenv (with flask installed) on the VB server, called myflaskv (/var/www/myflaskv)
- putting myflask dir into myflaskv (/var/www/myflaskv/myflask)

I did end with the following httpd.conf virtual host section:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/myflaskv/myflask"

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/myflaskv/myflask">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myflaskv/myflask/index.wsgi

    ServerName www.myflask.com:80

</VirtualHost>
```

I can load the page http://www.myflask.com (even with virtualenv activated) but I can't load the page http://www.myflask.com:5000 as I would suppose to debug.

So I tried to add a virtualhost on port 5000:

```
<VirtualHost *:5000>

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/myflaskv/myflask"

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/myflaskv/myflask">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myflaskv/myflask/index.wsgi

    ServerName www.myflaskv.com:5000

</VirtualHost>
```

supposing that this way I could load http://www.myfaskv.com, and instead I can't (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED).

By the way I temporarly disactivated ip-tables and se-linux.

So is there a way to load from browser the 127.0.0.1:5000 ip address of a remote host?
Or there is a better way to debug flask in an wsgi apache dev environment?

Comment: Debug mode has nothing to do with the port. If you want debug mode, you need to set `app.debug = True` somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the url from outside the box, you will have to run the server at `0.0.0.0:5000`.

The url `http://127.0.0.1:5000` cannot be accessed from outside the box you are running it in.

Answer (score 0):

When you use wsgi to access your app, the error messages and stack traces are written to the web server error log, by default at /var/log/apache2/error.log. You don't need to use the virtualenv web server. Just write any debug output you need to a local log file (if you have debugging input you want to print) and look for the stack traces in the apache error log.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I was actually looking at apache errror log but I couldn't get enough details about problems, I think flask debugger is more verbose.